# Maven plugin required parameter

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing my own Maven plugin. My Mojo has a required parameter list:

```
@Parameter(property = "map.packages", required = true)
private List<String> packages;
```

Now, when I run this plugin in a project with no configuration, I would expect the build to fail as the `packages` parameter is required. Instead I get `packages` as an empty list.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Ps. I probably should have added this to some issue tracker but where is Maven's issue tracker?

Comment: Can you show you pom file which you use to build your plugin? Causes it sound like something is wrong.

Comment: Have you correctly added the annotation api spec to your pom? `<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>`

Comment: Yep, all annotations are working except that required parameter.

Comment: Is the code of the plugin somewhere available to take a look into it? (github?)

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, https://github.com/NitorCreations/DomainReverseMapper/blob/master/drm-maven/src/main/java/com/nitorcreations/DomainMapperMojo.java

Comment: After taking a look into your Maven build you seemed to be violating many rules, best practices etc. (never check in eclipse configuration .settings etc.). Don't execute gpg signing in verify lify-cycle phase (if needed configure it for releasing). Javadoc should only be generated in site life-cycle. Ah btw. The issue tracker can be found on the [web-site](http://maven.apache.org/issue-tracking.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is located based on the property which can be observed via a debug output (with the help of an integration test) which looks like this:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          com.nitorcreations:drm-maven-plugin:1.1-SNAPSHOT:map (test-parameter)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}">${outputDir}</outputDirectory>
  <packages>${map.packages}</packages>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
</configuration>
```

Here you can see that the property (map.packages) will be injected into the package configuration parameter which means the configuration parameter has a value which fulfills the required parameter. If you need having a property defined in combination with required you need to check in the execute() method.

Answer (score -1):

according to this documentation http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html#The_Descriptor_and_Annotations you could try it with the @Required annotation

Comment: The `@required` is a Javadoc annotation and was superceded by Java 5 annotations mentioned on that same page you linked to.